# I would like to setup ble device simulator

Tags: android, python-3.x, bluetooth-lowenergy, simulation

As part of my work, i would like to have multiple (100+) BLE devices to test my application. At this moment I don't have that many devices. So, I wanted to simulate multiple BLE devices. I would like to know if there is a way to simulate multiple BLE devices programmatically. I should be able to simulate multiple BLE devices with single hardware/software.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not doable. This is because you will need a 100+ different unique baseband/HCI devices and for that you need different hardwares. The only thing I can think of is if you're able to change the hardware MAC address of a device - however I don't know of a single device that does this and it also violates the Bluetooth SIG specification.

What exactly is the functionality that you'd like to simulate? You might be able to do some sort of minor simulation depending on your use case (e.g. if you want your target device to read 100+ different advertising devices, then this is simple because there are many devices that keep changing their MAC address every few seconds for privacy reasons).

Comment: I do not generally agree with your answer. Example: My smartphone uses Googles/Apples ENF. So it pretends 144 times a day to be a different device. If the OP uses  random addresses I can't see how this violates the Bluetooth SIG specification. And devices that are able to change the BDADDR are available, for example the [Raspberry 4](https://community.infineon.com/t5/Wi-Fi-Bluetooth-for-Linux/How-to-change-Bluetooth-MAC-address-on-Raspberry-Pi-4/m-p/179479/highlight/true#M1115). But I agree with you, If the OP wants to have 100 devices  at exactly the same time, he needs 100 devices.

Comment: Yea I should've clarified - I meant it is not doable to simulate 100 devices "at the same time". Your suggestion of utilisation of the BLE privacy v1.2 feature of using a resolvable/non-resolvable random address is what I am pointing out in my second paragraph.